# How to unmarshal Transaction Payload in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I need to fetch transaction fields from a transaction in the ledger. I'm able to successfully query the transaction from ledger by invoking **qscc** chaincode but unable to parse the fetched transaction to retrieve transaction fields. I want to unmarshal the transaction content into a structure with all the fields. With the below code, I'm getting error **"failed to unmarshal channel header"**. Appreciate your help.

```
chainCodeArgs := toChaincodeArgs("GetTransactionByID", "myc", tid)
response := stub.InvokeChaincode("qscc", chainCodeArgs, "myc")
fmt.Printf("****************")
if response.Status != shim.OK {
errStr := fmt.Sprintf("Failed to query chaincode. Got error: %s", response.Payload)
fmt.Printf(errStr)
return "", fmt.Errorf(errStr)
}

respStr := fmt.Sprintf("successfully queried qscc chaincode. Got response: %s", response.Payload)
fmt.Printf(respStr)

payload, err := utils.UnmarshalPayload(response.Payload)
if err != nil {
return "", fmt.Errorf("Error when unmarshalling transaction payload response")
}
fmt.Printf("++++++++++++++++++++++")
fmt.Println(payload)

if payload.Header == nil {
return "", fmt.Errorf("error getting txID from header: payload header is nil")
}

chdr, err := utils.UnmarshalChannelHeader(payload.GetHeader().ChannelHeader)
if err != nil {
return "", fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal channel header")
}

fmt.Printf("++++++++++++++++++++++")
fmt.Printf(chdr.TxId)
```

Error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you also try to print the error that you are getting while unmarshling.

Comment: Sorry for missing that. I've included the screenshot of the error.

Answer (score 0):

the response payload is in []bytes

you can use `string(response.Payload)`

Above code is equivalent to .toString("utf8")

------ or ------

USE

```
var data interface{}

err = json.Unmarshal(responseBody, &data)
```